# Mapchart in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a map chart in excel, I'm creating a series of points using zipcodes, but once I'm done with the map I want to remove the borders around each zipcode. I have around 25000 points. I have accomplished this with the following code, but it takes about 2 hours to do this which is not efficient and also every time you try to open the file, it freezes for hours or it just crashes.

Thank you for you help.

```
Dim aChart As Chart
Dim serPoints As Long
Dim oSer As Series
Dim curPoint As Long

Set aChart = ActiveChart
Set oSer = aChart.SeriesCollection(1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

serPoints = oSer.Points.Count

'changes the border of the line to 0
For curPoint = 1 To serPoints
 oSer.Points(curPoint).Format.Line.Weight = 0

Next curPoint

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Here is the map before running the code 
[image: with borders around zipcodes]

and here is the map after I run the code 
[image]

Comment: Instead of looping, have you tried changing the line weight of the entire series at once? `aChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 0`

Comment: yes, I have tried that. When I do that, what it does it removes the outline of the whole map but not each individual point.

Comment: What about looping through the objects themselves: `For each curPoint in oSer.Points`? I might speed things up a bit. But for 25000 points, it will still take time, unless we can find a way to manipulate the entire collection at once

Comment: I have tried that too since i thought since we are using a for each loop it would run faster but it still took a long time and I'm still having that issue with the file itself loading once I open it again. Maybe my approach to this is wrong?

Comment: It's my understanding that on opening the file Excel will redraw the chart every time -- with the number of points you have, this would explain the delay every time you open it. What are you doing with the charts? Could you export them to Adobe Illustrator (print to PDF, then open and edit it in Illustrator) or a similar software?

Comment: The only problem with that is that those territories change, so the orange is Joe and the green one is john and they are in charge of those territories but I want Joe to take over more of johns territory, I made a form that replaces all of those zipcodes so Joe orange color would take some of the green color, so the map would change at that point. So If I did that I would need to edit it every time they made changes to it, I don't think that would be an option.